# Not being able to install react-native,while installing getting "npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT"

Tags: npm, react-native

I am trying to initialize react-native's Awesome Project. But whenver I try to run "react-native init AwesomeProject" command,It gives me following error.

```
Installing react-native package from npm...

npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "react-native"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 103.245.222.162:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/rushabh/AwesomeProject/npm-debug.log

`npm install --save react-native` failed
```

I am on stable internet connection. I have latest node and npm installed.
Please help.

Comment: Did you do what the error message told you to do?

Comment: my proxy setting is null. I can download everything but not being able to download ReactNative AwesomeProject. I don't think it is some issue with proxy.